# Google Plus API Share URL functionality removes hash fragments from URLs

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to share the following URL via the Google Plus API

http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html#h-4.1.1

I am using the following URL to share that:

https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html#h-4.1.1

However, the fragment is being removed, so I am only able to share the following

http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html

The documentation doesn't mention anything regarding constraints about hash fragments.

Has anyone already faced this issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

duh

Use %23 to encode #.

I thought I had already tested this.