# a href not taking url after # tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-plus

I am trying to get URL so that I can share it in google plus. I have tried doing it through various codes. The problem is that the ID value is hidden in url so I can't directly pass the url link in the a href tag. The latest code I am trying is :

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://abc.co/#!/newsdetail?Newsid={{item.Newsid}}" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
    <img src="xyz.png" alt="Share on Google+" style="height:22px"/>
</a>
```

In the URL only https://abc.co/#!/newsdetail is visible and the rest are hidden through localstorage.

Now when I try to share this page on google plus only the path https://abc.co is getting passed and I can only see the home page. How can I get the complete url. Please help me. I am new at javascript and angularjs.

Comment: Have a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370773/google-plus-api-share-url-functionality-removes-hash-fragments-from-urls

Answer (score 2):

`URLEncode` the link, so it will not truncate when the link is clicked by user into the browser.

Pass the following encoded URL ,

```
https%3A%2F%2Fabc.co%2F%23!%2Fnewsdetail%3FNewsid%3D%7B%7Bitem.Newsid%7D%7D
```

there will be `encodeURI()` function in Javascript as well

Comment: Can you please explain to me how this encoding works? I am new at this and don't have any idea about it

Comment: Browser will decode the encoded URL's automatically. It is suggested to encode the URL's to encode all special characters in URL string, in the format of %dd, so that the URL characters won't be mistaken for the actual JavaScript code syntax.

Comment: JavaScript provides encode(URL) method that does the encoding.

Comment: Can you please put try if the above encoded URL works on browser

Comment: @RamakanthPutta - There is no such function as `encode()` in JavaScript.

Comment: @31piy Yes, encodeURI() us the actual function.edited the response

Comment: @RamakanthPutta: well in this case, `encodeURIComponent()` is the need.